# Ajax POST Sends Null parameter to Controller in MVC

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to send data to the database.
Through Ajax POST to Controller
I've been searching everywhere trying to find a solution but none of them worked for me. I've tested Ajax Serialize() and it seems like it works fine but when I debug the Controller I find my Parameters are NULL.

Model:

```
public class AllFields
{
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string ProvinceId { get; set; }
    public string ProvinceName { get; set; }
    public string CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public string MaritalStatusId { get; set; }
    public string MaritalStatusDescription { get; set; }
    public string GenderId { get; set; }
    public string GenderDescription { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ID_Number { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string MedicationList { get; set; }
    public string EmergencyName { get; set; }
    public string EmergencyLastName { get; set; }
    public string Relationship { get; set; }
    public string EmergencyPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AddPatient(AllFields locationModel)
        {
            string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EnrollmentEntity"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Profile.spAddPatientProfile", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", locationModel.FirstName));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", locationModel.LastName));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID_Number", locationModel.ID_Number));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateOfBirth", locationModel.DateOfBirth));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GenderIDFK", Int32.Parse(locationModel.GenderId)));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PhoneNumber", locationModel.PhoneNumber));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Email", locationModel.Email));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Line1", locationModel.Line1));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Line2", locationModel.Line2));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CityIDFK", Int32.Parse(locationModel.CityId)));       
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProvinceIDFK", Int32.Parse(locationModel.ProvinceId)));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CountryIDFK", Int32.Parse(locationModel.CountryId)));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MaritalStatusIDFK", Int32.Parse(locationModel.MaritalStatusId)));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MedicationList", locationModel.MedicationList));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmergencyName", locationModel.EmergencyName));       
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmergencyLastName", locationModel.EmergencyLastName));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Relationship", locationModel.Relationship));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmergencyPhoneNumber", locationModel.EmergencyPhoneNumber));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Message", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    locationModel.Message = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@Message"].Value);

                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }

            }
            return new JsonResult { Data = locationModel, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };

        }
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/AddPatient",
            data: $("#fromHome").serialize(),   
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("successfully saved ");
            },
            error: function (xhr, value) {

                alert(" value from value: " + value.responseText);
            }
        })
```

Comment: What tag type is the tag with id "fromHome"? It has to be a <form> tag for this to work as you are expecting.

It could be worth having a look at this request in the network tag of your browser, and having a look at the request body to see what is actually sent.

Comment: locationModel == null, or the values within locationModel are null? I would recommend stripping down your model to just a couple columns to initially test behaviour with and identify potential problem fields. If some columns are not being populated, for form serialization you need to declare bound controls for each and every value in a model you want to send back. If not displayed you need hidden input fields otherwise the client form doesn't actually receive the model values to populate on the round trip.

Comment: Why dont you change the `dataType` in the ajax call to `application/json` and pass the stringified object?

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using application/x-www-form-urlencoded contentType add the action attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddPatient([FromForm] AllFields locationModel)
```

Comment: i tried it, it gives me a syntax error

Comment: @SamkeloNhlapo You have to post an error. Nobody can guess

Comment: Oh yeah i was supposed to add a using directive [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc] and i did but still sends null parameters

Comment: @SamkeloNhlapo What Mvc version are you using?

Comment: the version 5.2.7